# How to build an xml-based music search database?

Tags: php, xml, database

A while ago I built a PHP application for a local radio. They get requests from listeners and then put them into the application. The application then shows the DJ what the listener's requests are.

Now that all works fine but they have to build a music database by themselves which I use to search for music. My question is:

Is there an online music database that I can use cross scripting with soap/xml or something similar? I prefer XML but if there is a good database which gives the result in other format that won't be a problem.

I searched Google for this but I only find information how to download illegal mp3 files. I just need to find the music information like: album name, artist name and song title. Not the mp3/wma/etc file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find something useable here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_music_databases ?

Comment: That was exactly where I was looking for. Thank you and I will find my way from here.